# GROQ: query every element in an array

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, groq

I'm using Sanity/nextjs, and I want to query/fetch every image and their details out of an array (this is a unique slug). I've looked at the cheat sheet, and I've tried numerous methods of trying to do it, but nothing ever shows up on the page and the console isn't recording any errors.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext) => {
  const setSlug = pageContext.query.slug;

  const setQuery = `*[_type == 'set' && slug.current == $setSlug][0]`;
  const imagesQuery = `*[_type == 'set']{set_images[]{image{
    asset->{_id, url}, alt, name, date, size, materials}}}`;

  const setData = await client.fetch(setQuery, {setSlug});
  const imagesData = await client.fetch(imagesQuery, {setSlug})

  return {
    props: {setData, imagesData}
  }
```

Calling it like: `<li><img href={imagesData.image} /></li>`

Here's my schema, I'm trying to get everything within the `set_images`.

```
export default {
    name: 'set',
    type: 'document',
    title: 'Set',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'set_name',
            type: 'string',
            title: 'Set Name',
        },
        {
            name: 'slug',
            title: 'Slug',
            type: 'slug',
            options: {
                source: 'set_name'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'set_images',
            type: 'array',
            title: 'Set Images',
            of: [
                {
                    name: 'image',
                    type: 'image',
                    title: 'Image',
                    options: {
                        hotspot: true,
                    },
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: 'alt',
                            type: 'string',
                            title: 'Alternative Text',
                            options: {
                                isHighlighted: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'name',
                            type: 'string',
                            title: 'Name',
                            options: {
                                isHighlighted: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'date',
                            type: 'string',
                            title: 'Date',
                            options: {
                                isHighlighted: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'size',
                            type: 'string',
                            title: 'Size',
                            options: {
                                isHighlighted: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'materials',
                            type: 'string',
                            title: 'Materials',
                            options: {
                                isHighlighted: true
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Sanity, you need to generate Image URL with plugin like @sanity/image-url.

```
npm install --save @sanity/image-url
```

Configure it in your sanity client.

```
import React from 'react'
import myConfiguredSanityClient from './sanityClient'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(myConfiguredSanityClient)

function urlFor(source) {
  return builder.image(source)
}
```

Now just import the **urlFor** in your component and use for getting images.

```
<img src={urlFor(imagesData.image).url()} />
```

Comment: Sorry, I can see the error in my post here- I was already using urlFor, but in my tiredness, forgot to add that to the post (and mistyped my img call example, hence the href haha). It ended up being an issue with my schema, I'll post the answer now. Thank  you for responding though!

Answer (score 0):

**Correction for the post:** I was calling it like `src={urlFor(imagesData.image).auto('format').url()}`, not `<li><img href={imagesData.image} /></li>` (tired brain).

**Answer:**
I needed to change my schema so that my array was accepting an object with images in its field, not an image with fields as it returned every image as 'null'.

This reflects the change in my schema:

```
{...
            name: 'set_images',
            type: 'array',
            title: 'Set Images',
            of: [
                {
                    name: 'imageItem',
                    type: 'object',
                    title: 'Image Item',
                    options: {
                        hotspot: true,
                    },
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: 'image',
                            type: 'image',
                            title: 'Image'
                        },    ...
```

And this is how I queried it:

```
const imagesQuery = `*[_type == 'set' && slug.current == $setSlug][0]{'imageItems':set_images[]{image{
    asset->{_id, url}, alt, name, date, size, materials}}}`;
```

And made sure it was mapping through `imagesData.imageItems`